# Android Google Maps V2, MapView causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Note: I don't want to use MapFragment, because I'll need to overwrite a method inside the MapView!

I use following code to display my MapView:

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(null);
mapView.onResume();
```

With this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works great. But I have to export my project as a jar (closed source), so I can't use the xml layout anymore, right?

Because my layout is pretty simple, I can create it manually in the code.
So now I'm using this:

```
mapView = new MapView(context);
mapView.setLayoutParams(
    new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
);
view.addView(mapView);
mapView.onCreate(null);
```

But I get a NullPointerException on the onCreate statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Android Google Maps V2 then you have to use SupportMapFragment or MapFragment.

Comment: It says [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) that it's okay to directly use the MapView. I have to, because I need to override certain methods. But this isn't the issue as I know it works when using the MapView via the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GeoPosActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_weight="50"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I use this it's my app. and it work,

why do you use ".jar" ? For test your application use a device with android it's the best.

Comment: Because I want to distribute the library I'm writing to third party developers, but don't want to share my source code with them. So as far as I know, using a Android Library Project isn't the solution. My idea is to have a jar with the compiled code.